# Axis2 convert xs:boolean to java Boolean

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have an Axis2 web service where I want to allow null values on an xs:boolean field. I have tried to just change the boolean attribute in my pojo to a Boolean object which makes it possible to send in null values but instead it never is able to convert true to a Boolean but it always is false. Any idea if this can be solved?

To make it clear I have a services.xml where I specify the service class so it generates the web service and wsdl from the Java classes.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it on my own. The problem was that I had a getter called Boolean getXXX and also a method called boolean isXXX which seems to have caused the problem. Now I get the nillable in the wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but if am right `nillable="true"`   should map to `Boolean` wrapper class.

For example in WSDL you can define as below,

```
 <xs:element name="test" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
```

Comment: The problem is that im using Axis2 to generate the wsdl and I have not found a way to make it generate nillable=true.